# Multithreading an object with a public set list, and private set sublists

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin

I have a xamarin android app. I constantly get collection modified error or null reference errors, and I think it is because there is multithreading in the application.

My object which is used as a field in, and grabbed from a static State class when needed:

```
public static State {
    public ResultSet events { get; set; }
}

public class ResultSet {

    public List<Event> all { get; set; }

    public List<Event> activeEvents { get; private set; }
    public List<Event> flaggedEvents { get; private set; }
    public List<Event> inactiveEvents { get; private set; }

    public void AddEvent(Event e) {
        all.Add(e);

        RecalculateResultSets();
    }

    public void InactivateEvents(List<Event> events) {
        foreach (var event in events) {
           event.isActive = 0;
        }

        RecalculateResultSets();
    }

    private RecalculateResultSets() {
        activeEvents = all.Where(e => e.isActive = 1);
        inactiveEvents = all.Where(e => e.isActive = 0);
        flaggedEvents = all.Where(e => e.isflagged = 1);
    }

}
```

I am getting errors in other parts of my android app when I call:

```
var _events = state.events.activeEvents.Where(...)
```

or

```
var _events = events.activeEvents.Sort(...)
```

I have many different methods in ResultSet class like InactivateEvents(), AddEvents(), DeleteEvents(), UpdateActiveState(), etc that affects the "all" field, and the others get updated based on that.

Do I need to set a lock on "all" and release after the RecalculateResultSets runs in every single one of these methods? Do I also need a lock on activeEvents, etc so they are not read while they are being updated with RecalculateResultSets?

**Update:**
I've looked into using a ConcurrentDictionary, but my issue is that there are saved and unsaved events in the list, and all the unsaved events have an ID of 0. ConcurrentBag seems like it would be an issue because I need the list ordered by date.

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing the stack trace it's a little difficult to pinpoint the error.

You can try replacing your List with ConcurrentDictionary to handle multiple threading issues.

You can also try an object lock to lock access single a single thread.